# Appium pycharm can't start AppiumService() from code

Tags: python, appium

Executing the code

```
def startServer():
    service = AppiumService()
    driver = appium.webdriver.webdriver
    flag = False
    if (not flag):
        service.start()
        return service
```

to do this i need NodeJs.exe in my venv so after downloading the package: `pip install nodeenv`
when i try to install it with: `nodeenv mynodeenv`
I have not enough permission error.
I'm in windows 10 envivroment

Please can you help me on this ? Thanks

Comment: I would like to know if it's possible to launch the appium server in a venv pycharm. When i launch it from venv terminal i receive the error appium is not recognized as a intern or extern command.

Comment: Could you include whole error message / traceback to your question.